# Remote Spring RestAPI Server not responds on any requests

Tags: java, spring, rest, spring-boot

I have remote server with spring boot application, RestAPI. Server just doesn't respond on any request. I sent request using Postman or `-curl` and it just freeze without any responds.

Here is my spring configurations in **application.properties**:

```
server.port=8081
spring.datasource.url=jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/db
spring.datasource.username=blah-blah-user
spring.datasource.password=some-password
```

It starts after Logger was attached (java.util.logging), but I am not sure, that it is cause. I'm logging every method, which also writes to file. Before that it also was frozen. But, one day before, it was working good. Server also works - I logged by ssh, everything is okey.

Here is example of some method:

```
@SuppressWarnings("unused")
@RestController
@RequestMapping("/linksapi/v1")
public class MainController {

private static final Logger logger = Logger.getLogger("MyLogs");

...

@RequestMapping(value = "/hello", method = RequestMethod.GET)
public Map<String, String> hello() {
    Map<String, String> data = new HashMap<>();
    data.put("data", "Hello#_#World");
    log("Hello#_#World");
    return data;
}

private void log(String msg) {
    logger.log(Level.INFO, msg);
}
...
```

So, when I send request it should be written to logs, but it isn't.

What reason of this freezing can be? How to fix it?

**EDITED**

My curl is `curl http://107.180.67.211:8081/linksapi/v1/hello`

Comment: please paste your curl

Comment: Is it web proyect? can you paste your `web.xml` content?

Comment: @Valijon I don't have that file - it is just Spring boot web application, so I have just application.properties.

Comment: btw, locally it works very good, without such problems.

Comment: Do you have any proxy (ngix or similar) or similar in server to expose your app to public?

Comment: what do you do in the log method?

Comment: @Vincent sorry, I already edited my answer and put there log() methog

Comment: as Valijon said you have to check the server connectivity... If the server is in linux or unix check whether the previous server run was shut down properly...

Comment: @Vincent I restarted server, but it doesn't help me.

Comment: @Valijon it is only rest api, without any web implementation, so, I don't have any nginx. Sorry, maybe, I don't understand your question properly.

Comment: I started usual jar file to run my rest service. I have scripts to run it, should I publish it?

Comment: I am getting response for the provided curl

Comment: can you do this: start your app and do telnet to server port

Comment: Actually, it works fine

Comment: You have `RequestMapping("/api/v1")` but in your http request you have `linksapi`. How does that work?

Comment: Seems your app is shutdown when your close session. with linux, execute: `nohup java -jar ... &`

Comment: @RahulSharma they might have some redirects in apache

Comment: @RahulSharma no, I firstly wrote "api", because wanted to hide my url path, so, it is "linksapi" as well.

Comment: @Vincent maybe it is just server problems? I also connected from university's network, but I tried to send request from mobile network.

Comment: @Valijon I started my app in background process, so even after closing connection it should work

Comment: Okey, it works from mobile network, thank you, guys! :)